# Selenium Python throwing browser_switcher_service.cc(238) error for no reason

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I wrote a pretty simple script to ping a website -> find an element by name -> check if it's displayed or not. The script seems to be working fine but throwing a weird error at the same time.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

# Chrome 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='D:/selenium_drivers/chromedriver.exe')

driver.get("http://newtours.demoaut.com/")
element = driver.find_element_by_name('userName')
print(element.is_displayed()) # T/F based on element's state
```

Here is the output from this script,
[image]

I get the output as `True` which is great, but it comes along with this error for reasons I can't quite comprehend at the moment.
`[12080:16948:0505/181346.157:ERROR:browser_switcher_service.cc(238)] XXX Init()`
Google Chrome Version: 81.0.4044.129 (64-bit)
Selenium Chromedriver Version: 81.0.4044.69
Operating System: Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the purpose of this call is; but it appears to be a harmless logging call. The relavant code is:

```cpp
void BrowserSwitcherService::Init() {
  LOG(ERROR) << "XXX Init()";
  LoadRulesFromPrefs();
  StartDownload(fetch_delay());
}
```

Which was added in [this commit](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/79bf58880db534c9a29e378c12abd4bd92d7f158%5E%21). Does this do anything? Or just print a message to the console? Are any Python errors raised?

Comment: So far it has just been printing this message on the console and not raising any python errors. While I continue to explore Selenium, if it starts to create problems, I will update here.